Error: The "" scheme is not supported laravel
I have an error when try to send mail to mailhog with laravel, is the follow:
The "" scheme is not supported; supported schemes for mailer "smtp" are: "smtp", "smtps". 
Env file config:
MAIL_MAILER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=localhost    
MAIL_PORT=1025    
MAIL_USERNAME=null    
MAIL_PASSWORD=null    
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null    
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"    
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}" 

my route code:
Route::get('/email', function () {

    Mail::raw('Mensagem de teste de RH MANAGMENT', function (Message $message) {
        $message->to('test@gmail.com')->subject('Recursos Humanos RH')->from('rh@rhmanagment.com');
    });

});

Could soemone help me?

It seems like a relatively new issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/53721
Which should be fixed in the next release.
In the meantime, you should manually upgrade the symfony/mailer package.
composer require "symfony/mailer:~7.1.0"

If the issue persists try changing the MAIL_ENCRYPTION which should automatically set the scheme:
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

As discussed in the issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/53721#issuecomment-2513369358

Thank you, it solves with the symfony/mailer upgrade.

Thank you so much, this fixed it for me!

In my case a hint from Laracast forum solved it.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mailer-problem-scheme-is-not-supported-supported-schemes-for-mailer-smtp-are-smtp-smtps
They supposed to add
'scheme' => 'smtp'
in config/mail.php in 'mailers'=> 'smtp' section.

Thanks a lot! This also fixed it for me, because I also had MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl which worked fine before.

This is the actual fix.  I hope the add it to the next update, as otherwise I have a bunch of sites to go manually update.

In my case I solved it by changing MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl to MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls in .env file

mine was same as yours but this resolved it.
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
dont add any value to MAIL_ENCRYPTION, not even null or anything else.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had the issue in Laravel v11.34.2, but after upgrading to v11.35.0, the issue was solved.
